# EXTJS 4. How to set different editors in a grid for the same column?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

Consider a simple grid with one column. I want to edit this column using grid editor. The problem is that I want a different editor for each row. For example

1st row --> textfield

2nd row --> datefield

3rd row --> combobox

4th row --> textfield etc

When I click a column field (for example, second row) I use the setEditor method, but this seems to change the editor for the whole column not the specific row.

How can I achieve the specific functionality with extjs 4?

Comment: This is not how `gridpanel` is used normally. Have you had a look at `propertygrid`? It should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Propertygrid is ok for this. I described a simple case so the example is understood. The problem is that my grid has many columns not just two and I also want to interact with a database (load records to the grid with dataIndex).